# Cross page anchor works in all browsers but Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, anchor

I am having great difficulty in making cross page anchors work in Firefox:

http://www.work-form.co.uk/

When you click any of the carousel title links on the homepage, eg. "Astral Pattern", they should take you to the appropriate carousel on the "Work" page, it's working in Safari/Chrome but not Firefox.

I think it may be a CSS issue as the anchor links work when I disable the stylesheet in Firefox but I can't figure out how to get it to work by altering the CSS.

Here is the HTML:

```
<h2><a href="http://www.work-form.co.uk/category/work/#astralP">Astral Pattern</a></h2>
```

which links to:

```
<div id="astralP" class="top"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div.top{
  height:109px; /* fixed header height*/
  margin:-109px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: once the images are loaded it works with my FF (Version 28.0)

Comment: Thanks for checking, it's not working on my Firefox 29.0